# SQL Report for grouping by date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table which stores data like this:

```
ItemID   Date   Value

01       1/1/15  1

01       2/1/15  2

01       3/1/15  0

01       4/1/15  0

01       5/1/15  3

01       6/1/15  1
```

How do I generate a report in SQL which would show the begin and end dates of all zero periods per item?

In this example, I would get :

```
ItemID    Start    End

01        3/1/14   4/1/15
```

The condition is that there will be multiple zero periods during the year, and all of them should appear in the report (so simple group by will not do).

Thanks very much!

Comment: What if 6/1/15` is zero?

Comment: Do you want every `ItemID` to appear even if it has no 0 values?

Comment: We need more sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the `START` and `END` dates of all continuous zero `VALUE`.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd6e9/1/0)

```
;WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        RN = DATEADD(MONTH,- ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ItemID ORDER BY [Date]), [Date])
    FROM Test
    WHERE Value = 0
)
SELECT
    ItemID,
    Start = MIN([Date]),
    [End] = MAX([Date])
FROM Cte
GROUP BY
    ItemID, RN
```

**Sample Data**

```
ItemID Date       Value
------ ---------- -----------
01     2015-01-01 1
01     2015-02-01 2
01     2015-03-01 0
01     2015-04-01 0
01     2015-05-01 3
01     2015-06-01 1
01     2015-07-01 0
01     2015-08-01 0
01     2015-09-01 0
```

**RESULT**

```
ItemID Start      End
------ ---------- ----------
01     2015-03-01 2015-04-01
01     2015-07-01 2015-09-01
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is just what I needed. Adapted it to a case where the dates are stored as weeks, by putting WEEK into the DATEADD. Thanks!!!

Comment: Will not work if you will change the record from "01     2015-08-01 0" to "01     2015-08-01 1"

Comment: @sidux, what do you mean it will not work? It'll return three rows with the start-end combination: (2015-03-01, 2015-04-01), (2015-07-01, 2015-07-01) and (2015-09-01, 2015-09-01)

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution (works with 2012+):

```
with x as (
    select *,
    case when lag(value) over(partition by itemid order by date) <> value then 1 else 0 end as l
    from #t
),
y as (
    select *, sum(l) over(partition by itemid order by date) as grp 
    from x 
    where value = 0
)
select itemid, min(date), max(date)
from y
group by itemid, grp
order by itemid, grp
```